# ATK4 How to set up custom formatters?

Tags: atk4, php

I'm trying to pretty-up a dropdown field, and I'm not sure I'm taking the right approach. I have this model for which the field 'type' is to be a dropdown that displays a string, but stores an integer. To format the output, I've subclassed Grid as

```
class Model_Member extends MVCTable {
    function init() {
        parent::init();

        $this->addField('type')
            ->type('list')
            ->display(array('grid'=>'mbrtype'))
            ->caption('Member Type')
            ->listData(array('Guest','Associate','Full'))
            ;
    }
}
```

To format the output, I've subclassed Grid as

```
class Grid extends Grid_Basic {
    function format_mbrtype($field) {
        $mt=array('Guest','Associate','Full');
        $this->current_row[$field]=$mt[$this->current_row[$field]];
    }
}
```

When I load Member records my admin CRUD, I see this field populated with the numbers instead of the formatted data. I had expected the Controller to pick up the values passed into display() and execute my formatter instead of using the standard one.

Am I missing something here? I poked through the source, and my best guess as to the spot where things are going wrong is in MVCGrid.php, line 45. The call to formatType() on the Controller object does not include the field name as the third argument, which causes it to ignore the field's display collection's mappings and fall back to the Controller's $type_correspondence array.

Of course, I've only been working with ATK4 for a couple weeks now, so I may have just tied things together wrong. Is this the correct way of implementing a custom formatter?

Comment: The idea and implementation is on the right track. Probably something is overlooked. If you changed to display('mbrtype') does it properly use your formatter?

Comment: Changing to display('mbrtype') does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**there is a problem in ATK 4.1.3:**

There was actually a problem. You'll need to patch atk4-addons:

```
diff --git a/mvc/MVCGrid.php b/mvc/MVCGrid.php
index 90bd365..0fb0c0b 100644
--- a/mvc/MVCGrid.php
+++ b/mvc/MVCGrid.php
@@ -42,7 +42,7 @@ class MVCGrid extends Grid{
                $field=$this->getController()->getModel()->getField($field_name);
                if(is_null($field))throw new Exception_InitError("Field '$field_name' is not defined in the ".
                        get_class($this->getController()->getModel())." model");
-               if(is_null($type))$type=$this->getController()->formatType($field->datatype(),'grid');
+               if(is_null($type))$type=$this->getController()->formatType($field->datatype(),'grid',$field_name);
                if($field_name=='locked')return
                        parent::addColumn('locked','locked','');
         if($field_name=='id')$type='text';
```

Or open atk4-addons/mvc/MVCGrid.php, and on line 45, add 3rd argument to the call of formatType(....., $field_name);

and that should work.

### Alternatively

Upgrade atk4-addons to the "master" in github, which is still on 4.1 branch.

Demo: http://codepad.agiletoolkit.org/myformat

The correct way to defining "display" field is through array('grid'=>'myfield');

Thanks for noticing the problem!