# Grid formatter for uploaded file

Tags: atk4

I'd like to create a link in my grid to download uploaded files.

There is already several topics on it and the only solution that worked for me is: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/agile-toolkit-devel/degomDwwe1s/gGtcap-T27sJ

But I'd like more of an abstract solution which could work whatever the field name is. So I searched for adding formatter : [ATK4 How to set up custom formatters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898718/atk4-how-to-set-up-custom-formatters)

But it is never used...

I tried many things (v.4.2.5):

```
//in my model
$this->add('filestore\Field_File', 'file_id')
     ->display(array('form'=>'upload','grid'=>myField));

$this->hasOne('filestore\File', 'file_id', 'id')
     ->display(array('form'=>'upload', 'grid'=>'myField'));

//in filestore\FIELD_FILE
$this->display(array('form'=>'upload', 'grid'=>'myField'));

//my grid
class GridFile extends Grid
{
    function format_myField($field)
    {
        $fm = $this->add('filestore/Model_File');
        $fm->load($this->current_row[$field]);

        $src = $fm->getPath();
        $name = $fm->get('original_filename');
        $this->current_row_html[$field] = "<a href='$src'>$name</a>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Model:**

```
$this->addField("ipv4")
    ->display(["grid"=>"foo"]);
```

**Page:**

```
$g=$this->add("CRUD", ["grid_class"=>"XGrid"]);
```

**XGrid:**

```
class XGrid extends Grid {
    function format_foo($a,$b,$c=null){
        $this->current_row_html[$a] = "<b>".$this->current_row[$a]."</b>";
    }
}
```

Works like charm - perhaps your crud/grid not using the extended version. P.s. using latest atk version (master branch from git)